# Trouble with returning results from MySql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database-connection, connection-string

Edit: I solved my problem but if you have anything to add please do. Thanks

Note: I did not create the DB it was created by Wordpress hosted on GoDaddy with my site

I have a MySql Database called "wordpress" (for clarity).  I want to be able to grab the most recent post from my blog and show it on the landing page for my url.
So my thought is this: connect to the MySql DB, run a query to grab the most recent post, display the post.

I built a class to handle the connection and process the request:

```
public class DAL
    {
        private string connectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=[server here]; PORT=[port]; DATABASE=wordpress; 
            USER=[user name here]; PASSWORD=[password here];";
        private OdbcConnection blogConnection;

        public DAL()
        {
            blogConnection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public String[] GetRecentPost()
        {
            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM RecentPost";
            String[] recentPost = new String[3];

            //ODBC
            blogConnection.Open();

            OdbcCommand MySqlDB = new OdbcCommand(queryString, blogConnection);
            OdbcDataReader reader = MySqlDB.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.NextResult())
            {
                recentPost[0] = reader.GetString(0);
                recentPost[1] = reader.GetString(1);
            }
            recentPost[2] = reader.HasRows.ToString();
            blogConnection.Close();

            return recentPost;
        }
    }
```

In the `queryString` above `RecentPost` is a view I created to simplify the queryString since the query was a bit long.
I already know the view works. I tested it by opening phpMyAdmin from within the GoDaddy Hosting Center and executed the query above and I got the correct result, so I don't think the query/view is wrong.

The code-behind for the landing page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DAL dataAccess = new DAL();

            String[] recentPost = dataAccess.GetRecentPost();

            Title.Text = recentPost[0];
            Post.Text = recentPost[1];
            Extra.Text = recentPost[2];
        }
```

So when my page loads the `Title` and `Post` texts are empty and `Extra.Text` is `False` (which from the `DAL` is the value from `reader.HasRows`).
So my guess is that its connecting fine and running the query but maybe on the wrong database? I don't know.

I also tried to debug but then my code throws an error about trying to connect to database.

*So my questions are*: Do you see anything wrong with the connection string?

If not do you see anything else than would cause a connection to be esablished, a query to run, no exceptions thrown but no results returned?

Any one with experience trying to grab data from thier own wordpress blog?

Thanks for the help - this one has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why my original code wasn't working but I solved my issue.  For anyone else having this issue here is how I changed my code (in the `GetRecentPost` method) and solved my problem:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

//ODBC
blogConnection.Open();

OdbcDataAdapter MySqlDB = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, blogConnection);
MySqlDB.Fill(ds);
return ds.Tables[0];
```

So instead of an array of strings I used a `DataSet`.  Instead of using the `OdbcDataReader` I used an `OdbcDataAdapter` and populated the `DataSet` with the `.Fill()` method from `OdbcDataAdapter` I then returned the first table from the `DataSet` to my `Page_Load` method.

Here is my new `Page_Load()`:

```
DataTable table = dataAccess.GetRecentPost();

if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Title.Text = table.Rows[0]["title"].ToString();
    Post.Text = table.Rows[0]["content"].ToString();
}
else
    Extra.Text = table.Rows.Count.ToString(); \\if nothing was returned ouput the 0 just to be sure
```

Hope this helps anyone else with this issue

And thanks for anyone who took the time to look